# AEM CQ5 Move option for a file to another location

Tags: file, adobe, aem

I have Website configured in CQ5 AEM. I am trying to move some files to a folder on the same location. I have large count of files, each and every i should select and click on move to move files.

Any suggestion to move multiple files to a folder in the same location in adobe experience manager. In spent 1 day to send 150 files to a folder. I have almost 10000 files to move. Please suggest me to reduce my work.

I got some reference 
       http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/page_create_edit.html 
but it is showing for 1 single file using move option.

Appreciate and Thanks in advance. It helps me alot.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really about files, then you can try to connect to cq instance via WebDav and operate with files like in any file manager (but it does not work for me with pages and some other node types).

Otherwise, I would suggest to create package in package manager with all files (you want to move), download it, unzip, move required files to another folder, pack it back to package, upload and install. After that you can delete files in old location.

In second case, you, probably, will have to modify filter.xml according to new files' location.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question here, i can be able to see folders relevant to the pages i have created inside pacakage. there are few xml pages are also available if i delete the page. what if xml creates problems. I didnt tried it practically. i am working on staging server. I cant take risk in this. can suggest any feasible solution

Comment: @user1099855 sorry, I dont really understand your question. What xml file are you talking about? It would be cool for you to have local instance where you can test modified package. Also, before any changes, you should create a backup (package with pages to be moved, and pages already moved) so you can restore your current state.